# CSS: Same height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have a standard bootstrap-grid. The columns differ in their height sometimes which causes this:

[image]

Instead what I need is this:

[image]

I know, usually this is achieved by grouping 3 items in a row. But: as the browser resizes, it changes from a 3-column to a 2-column and then 1-column layout. So how can I achieve the same effect without using multiple rows?

**Code:**

```
<section class="container margin_60">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      // content
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      // content
    </div>
    ....
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Show your code, please.

Comment: @SergeyDenisov I added the code

Answer (score 1):

**Got it!**

The solution is indeed to add a *clear:both* after every 3rd element, so the next element can break. But as the grid shall be dynamic and switch the amount of columns, it cannot be implemented directly into the html.

> Solution: :nth-child

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .my-grid-item:nth-child(3n+4) {
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

For the 3-column layout and

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .my-grid-item:nth-child(2n+3) {
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

for 2-column and 1-column layout.

Comment: no need to add `+4`.
`.my-grid-item:nth-child(3n)` is enough ;)

Comment: The solution recommended by Bootstrap is to use `clearfix` at [specific responsive breakpoints](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets). That way you can avoid the custom CSS.

Answer (score 0):

After every 3 div add that div:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Comment: No, because when the grid changes to a 2-column layout the site doesn't work

Comment: @mstoldt ok then make a class for that css and add it.